# exporting j2me textfield inputs to CSV and XML

Tags: xml, csv, java-me

Hi I am new to J2ME and would like to know if it is possible to export j2ME user inputs into an XML file or in CSV file.

Currently I have a 'verication page' for user-inputs that displays all of the user input values for each textfield. Is there a way to export my 'verication' page into an XML file? or possibly a CSV file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at toByteArray method at http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databasemap/.

You could create similar methods for CSV and XML formats.